# Hide / mask URL for aux routes angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular4-router

Is it possible to mask somehow the aux route for the user (remove / mask in browser navigation bar)?

For example if you navigate using

```
http://localhost:4200/superuser/(superuser_sidemenu:sidemenu//superuser_content:contexts)
```

To do something like this

```
http://localhost:4200/superuser/contexts
```

I am looking for a way to use aux routes with masking at the same time in order to display a user friendly url.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

in your code "skipLocationChange" is necessary

```
this.router.navigate(
[{ outlets: { primary: ["reporte", JSON.stringify(consulta)] } }],
    {
    relativeTo: this.route.parent,
    preserveFragment: true,

    skipLocationChange: true

});
```